# Join string and None/string using optional delimiter

Tags: python, string

I am basically looking for the Python equivalent to this VB/VBA string operation:

```
FullName = LastName & ", " + FirstName
```

In VB/VBA `+` and `&` are both concatenation operators, but they differ in how they handle a Null value:

```
"Some string" + Null ==> Null
"Some string" & Null ==> "Some string"
```

This hidden feature allows for the first line of code I wrote to include a comma and space between the required LastName and the optional FirstName values.  If FirstName is Null (Null is the VB/VBA equiv of Python's None), FullName will be set to LastName with no trailing comma.

Is there a one-line idiomatic way to do this in Python?

*Technical Note*:
gnibbler's and eumiro's answers are not strictly the equivalent of VB/VBA's `+` and `&`.  Using their approaches, if FirstName is an empty string ("") rather than None, there will be no trailing comma.  In almost all cases this would be preferable to VB/VBA's result which would be to add the trailing comma with a blank FirstName.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
FullName = LastName + (", " + FirstName if FirstName else "")
```

Answer (score 128):

The following line can be used to concatenate more not-None elements:

```
FullName = ', '.join(filter(None, (LastName, FirstName)))
```

Comment: gnibbler's is clearest and best for a single simple concat.  But this one is exactly what I needed in my case of joining a whole list.

Comment: This is far clearer than the accepted answer and more pythonic in my mind.

Comment: PyCharm warns on this line: `expected type 'Iterable[str]', got 'Iterator[dict]' instead`

Comment: better than accepted answer. Because if `LastName` is None, FullName will contain "None".

Answer (score 0):

Simple ternary operator would do:

```
>>> s1, s
('abc', None)
>>> print(s if s is None else s1 + s)
None
>>> print(s1 if s is None else s1 + s)
abc
```